# TypeError: can't pickle function objects (can't pickle sklearn estimator)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, tokenize

It only happened when using jieba

my code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import jieba

data = ["十二届全国政协副秘书长黄小祥被免职撤委员资格－人事任免－时政频道－中工网", "银联持卡人境外可获紧急现金支援-财经网", "国家煤矿安全监察局关于印发《国家煤矿安全监察局领导同志工作分工》的通知", "扎克伯格净资产增至431亿美元 成第九大富豪 -科技频道-和讯网", "供电局领导注意了", "廊坊进口电源失电，全城大面积停电，请不要再打95598，今晚预计无法恢复送电！http://tieba.baidu.com/p/3077856046", "小区楼道因公摊电费争议被停电 供电部门:会彻查", "如何帮助员工“理解”战略-哈佛商业评论", "荣威950 1.8T正式上市 售17.98-20.98万_凤凰汽车_凤凰网", " 怀化电业局，你摊上事了，你摊上大事了！视频已经曝光，速度围观！ "]

jieba_tokenizer = lambda x: jieba.cut(x)

vect = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=jieba_tokenizer, min_df=3, max_df=0.95)

X_train_features = vect.fit_transform(data)
m = pickle.dumps(vect)
```

error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-556c978e0043> in <module>()
----> 1 pickle.dumps(vect)

C:\Python27\lib\copy_reg.pyc in _reduce_ex(self, proto)
     68     else:
     69         if base is self.__class__:
---> 70             raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
     71         state = base(self)
     72     args = (self.__class__, base, state)

TypeError: can't pickle function objects
```

chinese article need to use `jieba` as tokenizer, but I have no idea how to pickle that `vect` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the use of `lambda`, it should work if you instead use the syntax

```
def jieba_tokenizer(x):
    return jieba.cut(x)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! But why `lambda`  can not pickle ?

Comment: yeah i don't know , it's some python thing, i think there's other questions on stackoverflow about it

Comment: it's because python pickles by name reference, and a lambda doesn't have a name.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, the `dill` package pickles `lambda` transparently, and has the same API as `pickle`.

Comment: I just used it successfully to pickle a pipeline with a custom transformer that has a `lamba` buried in it. Took me forever to figure out where the `pickle.dump` was failing.